# Retrooper packetevents, is there a documentation of the version 2.0?

Tags: protocols, minecraft, bukkit, packet

I am searching for a documentation of the [PacketEvents API](https://github.com/retrooper/packetevents).
So that I can lookup secific problems, and directly learn good practice / inteded use.

Things I found:

- [packetevents-example](https://github.com/retrooper/packetevents-example/tree/a8ea407ec39d65efba95f7c75c734081223200ac)
  Somewhat helpful, but it does not cover much and is only for the
  1.8.4 version.
- [Javadocs](https://packetevents.github.io/javadocs/)    also not covering the 2.0 version, often not commented a lot.
- [Wiki](https://github.com/retrooper/packetevents/wiki) but I don't think it really covers anything.

---

currently, I am trying to understand how to send server-bound packets.

I found the method ProtocolManager#receivePacket(Object, PacketWrapper),
I have no idea what kind of object is expected (the variable name is `channel`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PacketEvents-Example library you linked does contain examples for 2.0. Select the `2.0` branch in the 'Switch branches/tags' dropdown. Here's a link to that: [PacketEvents-Example 2.0](https://github.com/retrooper/packetevents-example/tree/2.0).

You are correct that the Javadocs and Wiki only pertain to versions lower than 2.0 because 2.0 is a snapshot and not a full release.

Here's an example of how to send packets to a player in 2.0:

```java
PacketEvents.getAPI().getPlayerManager().sendPacket(player, packet);
```

Where `player` is your target player and `packet` is an instance of `PacketWrapper<?>` (e.g. `WrapperPlayServerPlayerInfo`).

That example is one of a few ways to send packets. As stated in the project's [README](https://github.com/retrooper/packetevents/blob/2.0/README.md), you should join their Discord for further help.

Comment: Nice that's really helpful. But I meant send packets to the server. (Like a player would send packets to the server) But I might find out myself with these new sources.